# IE 11 копирует состояние sessionStorage при открытии ссылки в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

При открытии ссылки в новой вкладке IE11 копирует состояние sessionStorage, хотя ожидаемое поведение, что sessionStorage будет пустой, как добиться ожидаемого поведения и возможно ли это?

Comment: Вы не правы.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage - "Открытие той же страницы в новом окне браузера или новой вкладке приводит к созданию новой сессии страницы, что отличается от поведения session cookies."

Comment: Действительно напутал

Comment: как именно ты открываешь новую вкладку?

Comment: Правой кнопкой, кликом на колесо.

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого то возникнет данная проблема, я использовал вот такой вариант её решения на TS на JS не сложно переписать:

```
 checkNewTabForIE(): void {
   if (this.utils.isIE()) {
     if (window.name === '') {
       if (!isNotNullOrUndefined(this.context.windowName)) {
         window.name = String(Date.now());
         this.context.windowName = window.name;
       } else {
         if (this.context.windowName !== window.name) {
           sessionStorage.clear();
           this.authS.logout();
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```